# Anomalous magnetic moment of the electron with different renormalization schemes

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, magnetic-moment

To compute the magnetic moment of the electron starting with the matrix element, including the current $J^\mu(x)$ and the external field $A_\mu$:

$<\psi_{p'\sigma'}|J^\mu(x)|\psi_{p\sigma}>A_\mu=e^{ik^\mu x_\mu}<\psi_{p'\sigma'}|J^\mu(0)|\psi_{p\sigma}>A_\mu $ ,$k^\mu=(p-p')^\mu$

so we can identify the last part with 3 point function $\Gamma^\mu$:
$<\psi_{p'\sigma'}|J^\mu(0)|\psi_{p\sigma}>=ie\cdot \bar  u(p',\sigma')\Gamma^\mu(p,p')u(p,\sigma)$

after spanning $\Gamma^\mu$ on the gamma matrix and momentum basis, in addition after using some identities we find that:

$\Gamma^\mu=F(k^2)\gamma^\mu-\frac{i}{2m}(p+p')G(k^2)$

When $F(k^2),G(k^2)$ are "electromagnetic form factors"
using more identities and the normalization of the wave function one found that after plugging $p=p'$:

$F(0)+G(0)=1$

After taking non relativistic limit and changing the form of $\Gamma^\mu$ in terms of the electromagnetic factors we found the coupling between spin and external magnetic field given with the anomalous magnetic moment of the electron:

$\mu=\frac{e}{2m}F(0)$

the next step can be done using diagram expansion of the 3 point function up to 1- loop correction (that what interesting us) to find $F(0)$ up to this order.

For **general renormalization**:

fermion field: $\hat \psi \to \sqrt{Z_2}\hat \psi$

current: $J^\mu \to Z_2J^\mu$

photon field: $A_\mu \to \sqrt{Z_3}A_\mu$

mass: $m_0\to m-\delta m$

the expansion is given diagrammatically by the following picture:
[image]

For the **on-shell renormalization scheme:**

the diagrams (2)-(5) "type I loop diagrams" vanish because the self-energy 1-loop $\Sigma( \gamma_\mu p^\mu)$ is vanished due to the condition that:

$\Sigma( \gamma_\mu p^\mu)|_{\gamma_\mu p^\mu=im}=\frac{\partial\Sigma( \gamma_\mu p^\mu)}{\partial{\gamma_\mu p^\mu}}|_{\gamma_\mu p^\mu=im}=0$

and only the diagram (6) - "Type II loop diagram" will contribute,
plus we have one more diagram:

[image]

taking all together we find that:

$F(0) = Z(2)+ \pi(k^2)$ (contribution of diagram (7)) + long integral (contribution of diagram (6))

$G(0) = $ other long integral (contribution of diagram (6))

so we finally get:

$\mu=\frac{e}{2m}F(0)=\frac{e}{2m}(1-G(0))$
(not taking account of $Z_2$ and $\pi(k^2)$
that influenced by the renormalization)

My question is:
In fact, we could choose a different set of renormalization conditions, e.g. ,**MS (minimal subtraction) scheme**, to define $Z_2$, $Z_3$ and $\delta m$. In particular,
it looks like for different choices of $Z_2$ we get the same $G(k^2)$ while $F(k^2)$ changes!? So $F(0)+G(0)=1$ is in jeopardy. What is a resolution to the apparent contradiction?

I think that for example for MS or general renormalization scheme the Type I loop diagrams (2)-(5) should contribute because now we have in general:
$\Sigma( \gamma_\mu p^\mu)|_{\gamma_\mu p^\mu=im}\ne 0 , \frac{\partial\Sigma( \gamma_\mu p^\mu)}{\partial{\gamma_\mu p^\mu}}|_{\gamma_\mu p^\mu=im}\ne 0$

But I still don`t understand how to show that including those diagrams will give me back the relation:

$F(0)+G(0)=1$